# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'num_samples'

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp, tensorflow2.0

i was following a tutorial from tensorflow v1.x, but at the last step i faced an issues which is:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'num_samples'
```

and here is below is the function:

```
def generate_text(model, start_string):
  # Evaluation step (generating text using the learned model)

  # Number of characters to generate
  num_generate = 1000

  # Converting our start string to numbers (vectorizing)
  input_eval = [char2idx[s] for s in start_string]
  input_eval = tf.expand_dims(input_eval, 0)

  # Empty string to store our results
  text_generated = []

  # Low temperatures results in more predictable text.
  # Higher temperatures results in more surprising text.
  # Experiment to find the best setting.
  temperature = 1.0

  # Here batch size == 1
  model.reset_states()
  for i in range(num_generate):
      predictions = model(input_eval)
      # remove the batch dimension
      predictions = tf.squeeze(predictions, 0)

      # using a multinomial distribution to predict the word returned by the model
      predictions = predictions / temperature
      predicted_id = tf.compat.v1.distributions.Multinomial(predictions, num_samples=1)[-1,0].numpy()
      #print(tf.multinomial(predictions, num_samples=1).shape)
      # We pass the predicted word as the next input to the model
      # along with the previous hidden state
      input_eval = tf.expand_dims([predicted_id], 0)

      text_generated.append(idx2char[predicted_id])

  return (start_string + ''.join(text_generated))
```

and the parameters of tf.compat.v1.distributions.Multinomial:

```
#tf.compat.v1.distributions.Multinomial(
#    total_count,
#    logits=None,
#    probs=None,
#    validate_args=False,
#    allow_nan_stats=True,
#    name='Multinomial'
#)
```

the tutorial link which i was following:
https://colab.research.google.com/github/zaidalyafeai/ARBML/blob/master/Interfaces/Notebooks/Arabic_Poem_Generation.ipynb

is there any suggestions, i need to make a test if this works, i will work around and upgrade to tensorflow 2.x, thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

i solved myself, the line of the issue is:

```
predicted_id = tf.compat.v1.distributions.Multinomial(predictions, num_samples='1')[-1,0].numpy()
```

which i checked tensorflow site:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/multinomial

which suggests to use:

```
tf.random.categorical
```

instead of :

```
tf.compat.v1.distributions.Multinomial
```

so the correct line became :

```
  predicted_id = tf.random.categorical(predictions, num_samples=1)[-1,0].numpy()
```